# Recursively manipulate string

Tags: java, string, recursion

```
    int index = 0;
    String str = "hello";

    String sFinal = add(str,index);
    System.out.println(sFinal);
}
public static String add (String str, int index){
    String sNew = "";
    if (index == str.length()){
        return sNew;

    }
    else{
        sNew+= str.charAt(index);
    }
    return add(str,index+=1);

}
```

All i am trying to do is to use a recursive function to loop though each char in an string and add it to an empty string

Comment: So, the second parameter exists solely to allow for recursion?  This seems like a very bizzarre way to tackle a very simple problem. Also, strings are immutable, so you're not actually appending anything to the original string, you're just making lots of copies for no reason then returning an empty string.

Comment: Please edit your answer with what exactly is going wrong with it (what you expect and what is actually happening). In the mean time, you need to pass two strings, one as a model string, and the other as a accumulator string. Right now you are resetting the accumulator every time.

Answer (score 1):

Your String `sNew` is a *local variable*, and it is set to be an empty string every time the `add` function is called, which doesn't give you the value of `sNew` from last iteration. You may modify it as follow:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int index = 0;
    String str = "hello";

    String sFinal = add(str, "", index);
    System.out.println(sFinal);
}

public static String add (String str, String sNew, int index){

    if (index == str.length()) {
        return sNew;    
    }
    else{
        sNew += str.charAt(index);
    }
    return add(str, sNew, index + 1);

}
```

Comment: Did you mean `index++` in the last line?

Comment: thanks for the feedback, im still a rookie at recursion!

Comment: @jahroy: `index++` wouldn't work; it'd pass the same `index` every time.  `++index` would work, but it's stupid for the same reasons `index+=1` is.  `index + 1` would be best.

Comment: @cHao - True.  I was just trying to correct the more obvious original typo, but you're correct (although I don't think any of the above mistakes are _stupid_).

Comment: @jahroy: `index+=1` isn't a typo either, AFAIK; it would work too.  The only thing wrong with it is that it modifies a local variable for no good reason.

Comment: Yes, again... It's not an error or a typo, but it is not standard, it's harder to read, it modifies a variable in an obscure and unnecessary way, and most importantly it's far less wonderful than your advice to use `index + 1`.

Answer (score 0):

While it is an odd way to build a string, I think you want something like this:

```
public static String add (String str, int index)
{
    // Terminate recursion
    if (index == str.length()) return "";

    // Build recursively
    return str.charAt(index) + add(str, index + 1);
}
```

Comment: interesting idea, less lines and more compact, thanks for the feedback!